# XSLT - Open HREF Automatically

Tags: javascript, xslt, xslt-1.0, href

I am working with **XSLT 1.0** to step through a large list of items and generate links that are used to access information regarding these items.

I have been able to successfully create `HREFs` for each item that, when clicked, open a new window and take me to the correct link and displaying the correct information.

While this is a big step in the right direction, there is one thing that I have not been able to figure out: How can I have the links open automatically when the XSLT is processed?

Here is an example **XML** document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<document>
    <example>
        <number>1</number>
    </example>
    <example>
        <number>2</number>
    </example>
    <example>
        <number>3</number>
    </example>
</document>
```

Here is my current **XSL** code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:oldxsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:local="#local-functions"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times">      

<xsl:template match="/">

    <html>

        <xsl:for-each select="//example">

            <xsl:element name="a">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                    <xsl:text>http://lmgtfy</xsl:text><xsl:text>.com/?q=Example+</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./number"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./number"/><br/>
            </xsl:element>

        </xsl:for-each>

    </html>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

***NOTE*** - The link in the example above is not meant to be offensive in any way, it is simply a short link that allows me to demonstrate what is actually taking place. (And yes, I have tried to search for a solution for this issue.)

Again, this is working as I would expect it to. When I click on any of the resulting links, I am taken where I should be.

All I would like to able to do now is open each link automatically once the page was loaded. (In this case, I should see 3 new windows appear without having to click any of the links.) If this is possible, please let me know how to accomplish this.

Thanks!

***UPDATE 1*** - If this can be solved, would it also be possible to open a print dialog for each link? If so, how?

***UPDATE 2*** - I did try to use Java to solve this, but I was unsuccessful. (Though I must be honest, I'm not very familiar with Java, let alone using it within an XSLT stylesheet.) Below is what I attempted, which is a modification of the coding above. It generated a line of text that was underlined like a link, but when clicked on, I received an error.

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="onload"><xsl:text>javascript:window.open('http://lmgtfy</xsl:text><xsl:text>.com/?q=Example+</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./number"/><xsl:text>','displayWindow','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="./number"/><br/>
</xsl:element>
```

***UPDATE 3*** - I was able to get Java to open a new a link in a new window, however this link is static. It does not vary with each item. Also, it only opens one window, even though there are three processes. Here's the code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    window.open("http://www.google.com");
    }
</script>

<body onload="load()">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="onload"><xsl:text>javascript:window.open('http://lmgtfy</xsl:text><xsl:text>.com/?q=Example+</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./number"/><xsl:text>','displayWindow','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes)</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="./number"/><br/>
    </xsl:element>
</body>
```

***UPDATE 4*** - I am making progress! With the following code, I am able to get a new window to open. The only problem I have now is that only one window opens, when I should be seeing 3. (The window that is opening is for the last/final link. In this case, "Example 3". That leads me to believe that the script itself is working and that I now only need to figure out how to call the script every time the `xsl:for-each` loops back.) Suggestions?

```
<xsl:for-each select="//example">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    xsl:text>javascript:window.open('http://lmgtfy</xsl:text><xsl:text>.com/?q=Example+</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./number"/><xsl:text>
    }
</script>

<body onload="load()">
    <xsl:element name="a">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="onload"><xsl:text>javascript:window.open('http://lmgtfy</xsl:text><xsl:text>.com/?q=Example+</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./number"/><xsl:text>','displayWindow','menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes)</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="./number"/><br/>
    </xsl:element>
</body>
```

Comment: Open the links should be basically possible  with al little bit JavaScript. But may be considered as popup and blocked.

Comment: What is the best way for me to go about doing this? (What little I tried with JS was not successful. Almost like JS isn't recognized?)

Comment: @hr_117 I tried to use Java, but was unsuccessful. I am only somewhat familiar with Javascript and I have no experience with using Java within an XSLT stylesheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I added what I attempted to the original post (See Update 2).

Comment: Construe a JavaScript HTML prototype first and after that works do the needed XSLT.

Comment: @JoopEggen I am not familiar enough with Java to even know what you mean by that...

Comment: I meant first writing manually an HTML page that opens the links. Then use that partly as "template" in the XSLT. I think the HTML is the problem. As XSLT is not easy too, do that later. Keep it simple.

Comment: @JoopEggen I have been able to get Java to open a static URL upon page loading that is entered into `<script>` tags. How would I go about getting this to open each page, however?

Comment: Instead of building in a loop all links `<a href>` you can build all your java script: `<script><xsl:for-each>...</xsl:for-each><script>`. Without the `xsl:element` creating an `<a>`. Good luck. BTW Java is not JavaScript.

Comment: @JoopEggen. You'll have to forgive my naivete with this. Can you please further explain what you mean? How will putting the `<xsl:for-each>` in `<script>` tags help, exactly? How would this allow the window to open? Please see Update 3 above and help me go from there. Thanks.

Comment: @JoopEggen I think I am pretty close. Please look at Update 4. The only problem I have now is that only one window is opening, not all of them.

Comment: I see you came to a solution. You can leave out "jaravascript:" before window.open, and in fact call window.open immediately, without a function load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it resolved thanks to the nudge in the right direction.

The solution is to create a new unique `script` and `function` within the `xsl:for-each` process and then call the `function` before going to the next loop.

Here's the working code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:oldxsl="http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-xsl"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:local="#local-functions"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    xmlns:lookup="lookup" exclude-result-prefixes="lookup">

<xsl:for-each select="//example">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function load()
    {
    xsl:text>javascript:window.open('http://lmgtfy</xsl:text><xsl:text>.com/?q=Example+</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./number"/><xsl:text>
    }
</script>

<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:text>#</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="target">_blank</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="./number"/><br/>
</xsl:element>

<script>
    load.call()
</script>

</xsl:for-each>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks again for all the help!